# Using VBA to copy dates from a .csv to a .xlsx switches the day and month

Tags: excel, vba, csv, copy-paste

I have a lot of experience with using VBA in Excel but I'm really struggling with something that feels like it should be straight forward:

I have a large number of .csv files and I would like to collate the data into one .xlsx file. The data is a list of dates and time in column A and then corresponding figures in columns B and C. I'm using the code below to open each .csv one at a time, copy the relevant data and paste it into the .xlsx.

The problem is that when I paste the data, Excel is swapping the day and month for days 1 to 12 of the month (e.g. 02/01/2023 becomes 01/02/2023), IT IS EVEN CHANGING THEM IN THE .CSV. I know there can be issues with date formats but the fact that it is changing in the file I am copying FROM has really baffled me.

In an attempt to fix this I am changing the format of my dates column to match that of the .csv (CUSTOM: "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm") before and after the paste operation, but to no avail. I've also tried a straight copy paste vs pasteValues and it doesn't make any difference. I've also tried looping through each cell in the range and using xlsCell.value = csvCell.value, but I still get the same result.

Here is my code:

```
Sub collateData()

Dim StrFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook, swb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim pasteRow As Integer, headerRowCount As Integer, count As Integer

headerRowCount = 8
pasteRow = headerRowCount + 1

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/Member ID - LJW6127 - collated.xlsx")

StrFile = Dir("C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Member Id - LJW61Z7\*.csv")

Do While Len(StrFile) > 0

    If Len(StrFile) = 26 Then
        
        Set swb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Member Id - LJW61Z7\" & StrFile)
        
        Set sht = swb.Sheets(1)
        
        wb.Sheets("Hourly").Columns(1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"
        
        sht.Range("A9:C" & sht.UsedRange.Rows.count).Copy
        wb.Sheets("Hourly").Range("A" & pasteRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
        pasteRow = pasteRow + sht.UsedRange.Rows.count - headerRowCount
            
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        swb.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        
        DoEvents
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    End If
    
    StrFile = Dir
    
Loop
        
wb.Sheets("Hourly").Columns(1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: For a starter - to avoid the CSV being overwritten try using `swb.Close SaveChanges:=False`

Comment: Have you tried changing the date format of `sht` - i.e. the source column. Once you have loaded it into Excel the damage has been done.
Also - instead of cut & paste, try `wb.Sheets("Hourly").Range("A" & pasteRow).Value = sht.Range("A9:C" & sht.UsedRange.Rows.count).Value`

Comment: Instead of using this approach use the `.ListObjects.Add` method. Record a macro and then import the csv file using `Data Tab | From text`. See what code does excel spit out. Also check the date formats now.

Comment: You don't specify how the source date in your CSV file appears exactly. I would suggest you use a [`Date` type in VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/date-data-type) , then normalize the read to a date from code. This will make it a lot simpler to control output, independent of system locale etc.

Comment: @CHill60 thanks, will add savechanges = False.

Comment: @CHill60 as I mentioned in the post, I have looped through the cells and tried .value = .value. When I tried in the way you suggest, it just copied the first value into every cell.

Comment: @MyICQ I mentioned that the format is CUSTOM: "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm". An example of one of the dates/times is "02/01/2023  00:10:00", which copies as "01/02/2023  00:10:00". I've just tried the following: Dim dt as Date: dt = srcCell.value: debug.print dt: targetCell.value = dt. The debug.print shows that the is "01/02/2023" and the result is the same. Is there a way I can change that?

Comment: Thanks for your suggest @SiddharthRout, I didn't get the chance to try it because another solution has been suggested that worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [OpenText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbooks.OpenText) method

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub collateData()

    Const HDR = 8
    Const CSVFOLDER = "C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Member Id - LJW61Z7\"
    Const TARGET = "Member ID - LJW6127 - collated.xlsx"

    Dim wb As Workbook, rng As Range, ar
    Dim lastRow As Long, n As Long, StrFile As String
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & TARGET)
    With wb.Sheets("Hourly")
        .Columns(1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"
        Set rng = .Cells(HDR + 1, "A")
    End With
    
    StrFile = Dir(CSVFOLDER & "*.csv")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    
        If Len(StrFile) = 26 Then
            
            Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=CSVFOLDER & StrFile, Origin:=xlWindows, _
               DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True, local:=True, _
               FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 4), Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1))
            
            With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
                lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                ' copy to array
                ar = .Range("A" & HDR + 1 & ":C" & lastRow)
                ActiveWorkbook.Close False
            End With
            
            ' update values
            rng.Resize(UBound(ar), UBound(ar, 2)) = ar
            Set rng = rng.Offset(UBound(ar))
            n = n + 1
            
        End If
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox n & " csv files imported", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes! This worked, thank you so much! I wasn't familiar with .OpenText. Forever learning : )

Comment: By the way, do you know why Excel behaves like that in the first place? Changing the data on the source sheet seems very strange to me.

Comment: @kwibbler I would guess its because csv files being plain text have no formatting information to tell excel what the date format is and it assumes it is USA format.  The opentext method has a local:= True property which tells excel to use your regional setting.